# enable_star on SPHINX Search Engine not working

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I use Sphinx v 0.9.9 and i need to search a `substring within a string`;

I enabled the start sintax, `enable_star = 1`, i restarted the entire system and still no results;

```
index job1
{
    source      = jobSource1
    path        = /home/sphinx/jobs/job1
    docinfo     = extern
    charset_type    = utf-8
    enable_star = 1
}
```

I read the docs from here: [sphinx start syntax](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-enable-star) and also [substring search](http://sphinxsearch.com/info/faq/#substring-search)

Any ideas?

Comment: upgrade to 2.0.6 or 2.1.1, 0.9.9 is almost 3 years old

Comment: i know, it is not up to me to update; i cant update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `min_prefix_len` and `min_infix_len` like it says in the documentation, and then re-index your data.

Comment: i did that now, still the same result

Comment: Small comment. At least in my version of SPH, you need to specify **only one of** `min_prefix_len` or `min_infix_len`.